# Swing Worker not refreshing JFrame properly

Tags: java, swing, jframe, swingworker

I originally was attempting to update a JFrame and JPanel several times while in a Java Action Listener, but both would only update when the Action Listener completed all its tasks.  Here is the link to my original question ([Refreshing a JFrame while in an Action Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539208/refreshing-a-jframe-while-in-an-action-listener)).

I was told in the feedback to that question that Swing Worker should solve my problems.  However, when I implemented Swing Worker (as seen below), nothing changed.  The JFrame and JPanel still updated only when the Action Listener completed all tasks.  My question is, am I missing something below?  If not, how can I implement this in an Action Listener to properly update the Frame and Panel timely?

```
@Override
protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception{
    //Downloads and unzips the first video.  
    if(cameraBoolean==true)
        panel.add(this.downloadRecording(camera, recording));
    else
        panel.add(new JLabel("Could not contact camera "+camera.getName()));

    panel.repaint();
    jframe.repaint();
    return 1;
}

private JLabel downloadRecording(Camera camera, Recording recording){
    //does a bunch of calculations and returns a jLabel, and works correctly
}

protected void done(){
    try{
        Date currentTime = new Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jframe, "Camera "+camera.getName()+" finished downloading at "+currentTime.getTime());
    }catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not call any methods on any swing objects, nor construct any swing objects, from inside the `doInBackground` method, nor call any methods which do so directly.  Your `doInBackground` calls to `.add`, `.repaint`, `new JLabel`, all violate this rule.  Modify the gui only from inside SwingWorker's `process` or `done`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a misundertanding about how `SwingWorker` works. This class is intended to provide a way to update the GUI while heavy tasks are being performed. All of this is because `Swing` components updates take place in the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://www.google.com.ar/#q=event+dispatch+thread) (a.k.a. EDT) which is a particular thread.

For instance, if you click a button and perform a time consuming task all in the EDT, then this thread will block untill this task finishes. Consequently, you'll see your GUI is frozen.

Keeping this in mind, [doInBackground()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#doInBackground%28%29) method runs in another different thread that's not the EDT which is ok. So don't call any `Swing` method in there:

```
protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception{
    //Downloads and unzips the first video.  
    if(cameraBoolean==true) // just use if(cameraBoolean), since this is a boolean
        panel.add(this.downloadRecording(camera, recording)); // NO!
    else
        panel.add(new JLabel("Could not contact camera "+camera.getName())); //NO!

    panel.repaint(); //NO, never!
    jframe.repaint();//NO, never!
    return 1;
}
```

Add a `JLabel` to this `panel` *before* executing your `SwingWorker` and update its text using [publish()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#publish%28V...%29) and [process()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#process%28java.util.List%29) methods instead:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
final JLabel progressLabel = new JLabel("Some text before executing SwingWorker");
panel.add(progressLabel);

SwingWorker<Integer, String> worker = new SwingWorker<Integer, String>() {    
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
        if(cameraBoolean){
            pubish("Starting long process...");
            //Some processing here
            publish("Intermediate result to be published #1");
            //Some other processing stuff
            publish("Intermediate result to be published #2");
            //And so on...
            return 0;
        } else {
            publish("Could not contact camera "+camera.getName());
            return -1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
        for(String string : chunks){
            progressLabel.setText(string);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        progressLabel.setText("Finished!!!");
    }
};

worker.execute();
```

Both `process()` and [done()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#done%28%29) methods take place in the EDT so it's safe make GUI updates there. Take a look to this excelent example: [Swing Worker Example](http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/) for more details.

Comment: This makes sense.  I was thinking that publish was the key somehow, and I was also wondering about using Swing components in SwingWorker.  

One question I still have, though, is will i need to call this.proccess() in .doInBackground()?

Comment: Hi there! No, actually you never call `process()` method explicitly. Every call to `publish()` method puts a value (chunk) in a queue that will be processed asynchronously  by the `SwingWorker` itself through `process()` method. This way the `SwingWorker` ensures `process()` method runs in the EDT. So you just have to define what `process()` method must do but you never call it explicitly. @austinthemassive

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Since you say process() is in the EDT, could I just add the label to the panel there?

Comment: Yes you can and it's ok. Don´t forget to call `panel.revalidate()` after adding the label. @austinthemassive

Comment: I did, and it now works!  Thanks for following up.  I was going to update this thread when I had some extra time.

In short, my understanding of Swing Worker was off, but now I'm good to go.

Comment: this answer makes me happiest person in the world,gratz.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you repaint your panel/frame just when the synchronous call `this.downloadRecording(camera, recording)` is finished?

Try to only put this call into the `doInBackground()` method, because (so I guess) that's the one that takes a long time and for all this time the JFrame gets not refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update UI in next way:

```
 panel.repaint();
 jframe.repaint();
```

In your `doInBackground` method you must to call `publish(V... chunks)` method, that `Sends data chunks to the process(java.util.List<V>) method.`(according docs) and than in method `process(List<V> chunks)` you can update your UI(according docs process method - `Receives data chunks from the publish method asynchronously on the Event Dispatch Thread.`). [SwingWorker docs.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)

So, override `process` method for updating, and call `publish` method.

Also you  can use **Executors** for background processes. In this case your UI will be working in EDT and your background process in another thread. Example:

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // run background process

        }
    });
```

EDIT: [good example of SwingWorker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15710814/progress-bar-updater-using-up-cpu/15710912#15710912)